# Simplifying $\binom{n}{k}$ / $\binom{n}{k-1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

So the question is as follows:

Simplify 
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n}{k-1}}.
$$

And this is what I got:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n}{k-1}}   &= \frac{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}}{\frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!(k-1)!}}\\[1em]
&= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} \times \frac{(n-k-1)!(k-1)!}{n!}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(n-k-1)!(k-1)!}{(n-k)!k!}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\left(\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-k)}\right)\left(\frac{k!}{k}\right)}{(n-k)!k!}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\frac{(n-k)!k!}{(n-k)k}}{(n-k)!k!}\\[1em]
&= \frac{1}{(n-k)k}.
\end{align*}$$

However, my textbook says that the answer is

$$\frac{n-k+1}{k}.$$

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should learn the basics of writing equations using the following guide as a tutorial. It is fairly easy, but you will have a better chance of having your question answered.  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Dr.MV One thing I learned a while back was that, even in comments, you do not have to paste a "naked link"; that is, you can hyperlink what you want to share by using `[text](link)`. So, for example, you linking to the tutorial can be done as follows: See the `[tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)` which renders as: See the [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ha--nice catch on the division symbol in the title. I'm so used to using the backslash now with programming and $\rm\LaTeX$ that I occasionally have a brain fart and forgot how to write the "divides" symbol. :(

Comment: Thanks Therapist.  I am adding more and more to my arsenal herein from your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!},
$$
and
$$
\binom{n}{k-1}=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}. 
$$
Thus, we will have the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n}{k-1}} &= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{(n-k)!(n-k+1)(k-1)!}{n!}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{(n-k+1)(k-1)!}{k(k-1)!}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{n-k+1}{k}.
\end{align}
This confirms what the book had as the answer.

Comment: Thank you. 
I see where I went wrong now.

Comment: @BrockFeenan Cool. Glad I could help--oftentimes proving binomial coefficient identities algebraically amounts to manipulating the factorials in some form or fashion.

Comment: You have a typo (an omitted factorial) in your third equation. It gets canceled in the next line, so I see why you made the mistake :)

Comment: @Ian Wait where is the typo? Could you fix it if my answer contains an error? I don't see it.

Comment: @therapist Never mind, I see my mistake now. You broke up $(n-k+1)!$ into $(n-k+1)(n-k)!$ without isolating it as a step. Carry on. +1.

Comment: @Ian Ah, thanks. Yes, I did skip a couple of steps with breaking $(n-k+1)!$ and $k!$--maybe a little sloppy, but the OP seemed to "know what was up." Thanks for making me read it again though. :) Always good to proofread!